# What does a resolver do if DNSSEC is properly configured on a server that isn't reporting to be authoritative

Tags: dns, dnssec

Does DNSSEC require that my `NS1` and `NS2` stored at the registrar be authoritative, or just that they answer for the domain? Can they be non-authoritative DNS servers answer the query?

Does anything specify what happens at that point in time?

From the BIND DNSSEC Guide,

[image]

What happens in the above circumstance if the fbi.gov name server that is written in the `ns1` at the registrar is non-authoritative but has all the appropriate records?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

DNSSEC doesn't add any restriction on this, but NS records are supposed to point to authoritative servers.

> *Authoritative Server*   A server that knows the content of a DNS zone
> from local knowledge, and thus can answer
> queries about that zone without needing to
> query other servers.
>
> [RFC 2182 Section 2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2182#section-2)

> Can they be non-authoritative DNS servers answer the query?

Authoritative servers and resolvers can answer DNSSEC queries as long as the answer they provide has valid DNSSEC records (assuming the client checks)

Comment: Your quote defines an *"Authoritative Server" but it doesn't say that the NS records are supposed to point to one.

Comment: [RFC 1035](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035.html#section-3.3.11) states that the RDATA of an NS record should contain `A <domain-name> which specifies a host which should be authoritative for the specified class and domain`. There are valid cases for a NS record to point to a non authoritative server, but usually this is not what you want.